# Who are the two extra teachers from the end of the USJ arc?

Tags: character-identification, my-hero-academia

[image]

At the end of the USJ arc, S1 E13 of the Boku No Hero Academia anime, there is a splash screen of the backup that was arrived to fight the League of Villains.  From right to left they are:

1 - Vlad King
2 - Nezu
3 - Iida Tenya
4 - Cementoss
5 - ?
6 - Ectoplasm
7 - Snipe
8 - Hound Dog
9 - Midnight
10 - Power Loader
11 - Present Mic
12 - ?

I do not recognize and cannot find #5 (the blonde person in the purple visor/glasses), or #12, (the pink haired person in the mask with tubes coming out of it).

Are these characters ever identified anywhere?  Or are the just a minor addition for the anime?

EDIT:
Amusingly enough, blonde visor has made a second appearance.  He was in the background of a scene at UA in the second MHA movie, Heroes Rising.

Comment: Looking at [the Wikia's list of people in that episode](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_13#Characters_in_Order_of_Appearance) they weren't mentioned

Comment: Still not enough for a proper answer, but they can be seen also in the Sports Festival episodes at the beginning of season 2, sitting with other teachers in a separate sector of the first year arena; it can be therefore guessed that they teach _something_ to _a first year class_.

Comment: @lfurini - Right you are.  Season 2, Episode 15 time 13:04.  Maybe others, too, but that is the first time and both are there.

Answer (score -2):

They are probably teachers for 3-A and 3-B.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this answer a bit, and perhaps adding a citation of some sort? This is super-brief.

Comment: During the Sports Festival they are seen at the first year arena (each school year has its own arena and competitions): if they only teach to 3-A and 3-B students, wouldn't it be strange for them not to watch their pupils' final performances?